# Where do i put mdl files for function SetModel

Tags: file, model, entity, garrys-mod

I am new in lua and gmod coding. I have already coded successfully a HUD's addons but i am stuck in another.

I want to create a new entity, and after reading lots of tutorial, i manage to do it but in game, the word ERROR appears in red when spawning, not the model. The server and the client are located on the same PC, for debugging considerations. I try to put mdl files on several folders without aby change.

I put mdl file in
`addons/models/model.mdl`

I think the client doesn't find the model file : do i need a workshop content even for testing ? Where do i put the files ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. When reusing existing MDL file, i must keep the original path for files.
That is, when opening mdl file, a path is writing at the begining. This path must be the same in the models subfolder of the addons (path and filename).